# I am getting gradle error while building app in flutter, it says could not found com.and.build.tools blah blah

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I have upgraded my gradle to 8.0

now whenever i try to build gradle with the command line i get the error saying problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration 'classpath'.

> Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.1.

```
 Searched in the following locations:

   - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/8.1.1/gradle-8.1.1.pom

   - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/8.1.1/gradle-8.1.1.pom

 Required by:

     unspecified:unspecified:unspecified
```

i have tried other versions of gradle also

- What went wrong:

A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.

> Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.

Searched in the following locations:

```
- https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.4/gradle-7.4.pom

- https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.4/gradle-7.4.pom
```

Required by:

```
 project :
```

but it is the same, can someone please help me out, please please, i have been trying to solve it for weeks but nothing has been resolved

tried everything, other gradle versions agps, but found nothing

Comment: How did you solved it?